# Angular : How two open two mat-menu in one HTML?

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image]

Here I have two matmenus in one component's HTML. When open second matmenu(the second matmenu is open when I right click on that div) but it is open the first matmenu so how to open both menus in one component HTML differently on different click in angular?

HTML

```
(this is first menu)
<mat-icon style="cursor: pointer;" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">more_vert   
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu"> 
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="addNewItem()">New Folder</button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="uploadFiles()">Upload Files</button>
  </mat-menu> 
</mat-icon>

(This is second menu)

<mat-card *ngFor="let imagespayload of uploadedImagesObj"(click)="activeFolder=imagespayload"
   (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, imagespayload)">

   <div style="position: fixed"
     [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
     [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y"
     [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu"
     [matMenuTriggerData]="{item: imagespayload}">
   </div>

  <mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-item="item">
      <button mat-menu-item>Action 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Action 2</button>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-menu>
```

TS

```
  import { Component, OnInit, Input,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material';

  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) contextMenu: MatMenuTrigger;
  contextMenuPosition = { x: '0px', y: '0px' };

 onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent, imagespayload) {
   event.preventDefault();
   this.contextMenuPosition.x = event.clientX + 'px';
   this.contextMenuPosition.y = event.clientY + 'px';
   this.contextMenu.menuData = { imagespayload};
   this.contextMenu.openMenu();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first menu is opening instead of the second because `@ViewChild()` binds to the first directive that matches the given selector, which in this case is the matMenuTrigger for your first menu. To bind it to your second menu trigger instead, use a template reference variable on the element with the trigger:

```
<div #trigger="matMenuTrigger"
    style="position: fixed"
    [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
    [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu"
    [matMenuTriggerData]="{item: imagespayload}">
</div>
```

Then, in your .ts:

```
@ViewChild('trigger') trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

this.trigger.openMenu();
```

For reference, see the [Angular ViewChild documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description), the [MatMenuTrigger API](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuTrigger), and [this post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/handle-template-reference-variables-with-directives-223081bc70c2) on using template reference variables with directives.